# googleConsumerKey and googleConsumerSecret for DotNotOpenAuth library

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webforms, dotnetopenauth

I am completely new to DotNetOpenAuth library and am currently trying to use it in a WebForms ASP.Net website project. I have successfully installed the library in my website using Nuget.

However, when looking at the samples for this library, I found the following 2 keys in web config. I did go to the sign-up URL mentioned, but could not get these keys. I also tried looking up the docs for this library, but could not find any thing on these 2 keys.

```
<!-- Google sign-up: https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageDomains -->
<add key="googleConsumerKey" value="anonymous" />
<add key="googleConsumerSecret" value="anonymous" />
```

**Question**

How do I get `googleConsumerKey and googleConsumerSecret` for use with my website, so I can have users login using their Google account?

Answer (score 1):

It can be difficult to find, there is soooo much google stuff that they offer that sometimes the thing you want is not easy to find.

Try

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

For Capcha keys use

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin

Comment: Thanks for those links. I will have a look at them. As you said, the search results in google only adds to the confusion.